# cannot infer type for type parameter `I` declared on the associated function

Tags: rust

```rust
use intbits::{Bits, BitsIndex};
use num_traits::int::PrimInt;

fn setbit<T>(mask: &mut T)
where
    T: Bits + BitsIndex<T> + PrimInt,
{
    let pos = mask.trailing_zeros();
    mask.set_bit(pos.into(), false);
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = 0b0000_1000u8;
    setbit(&mut m);
    println!("{:08b}", m);
}
```

Compilation failed with the error:

```
mask.set_bit(pos.into(), false);
     ^^^^^^^ ---------- this method call resolves to `T`
     |
     cannot infer type for type parameter `I` declared on the associated function `set_bit`
```

I'm not sure why it couldn't infer the type parameter. Here [`set_bit`](https://docs.rs/intbits/0.2.0/intbits/trait.Bits.html#tymethod.set_bit) requires its first argument to be bounded on the trait `BitsIndex<Self>`. I specified `T` to implements `BitsIndex<T>` and because `mask` is of type `T`, shouldn't the compiler infer that `BitsIndex<T>` equals `BitsIndex<Self>` on line 8?

## Update

I think I figured out. The code below works.

One problem with my previous code is that `u32` can't necessarily be converted `into` whatever `T` is. We need to use `try_into`, therefore `T` needs to be bounded on `TryFrom<u32>`.

Then adding `::<T>` to `set_bit` helps the compiler infer the correct types. But I'm not sure why it's needed in this case. From error message above, it seems that the compiler can already infer that `pos.into()` is of type `T`.

```rust
use intbits::{Bits, BitsIndex};
use num_traits::int::PrimInt;
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn setbit<T>(mask: &mut T)
where
    T: Bits + BitsIndex<T> + PrimInt + std::convert::TryFrom<u32>,
    <T as std::convert::TryFrom<u32>>::Error: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    let pos = mask.trailing_zeros();
    mask.set_bit::<T>(pos.try_into().unwrap(), false);
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = 0b0000_1000u8;
    setbit(&mut m);
    println!("{:08b}", m);
}
```

Comment: You aren't passing a `T` to `set_bits`, you're passing `pos.into()`. What is `pos` supposed to be coverting into? Can't you just pass `pos` directly?

Comment: @kmdreko `trailing_zeros` returns `u32` which needs to be converted to `T`. My original code incorrectly uses `into`. It should be `try_into` instead.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster I didn't post my solution was an answer because I only figured it out via trial and error, without really understanding it :) I will read Rust-specific MRE tips to make sure my future questions are clean and easier to understand. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to force `T` to be both `Bits` and its own index `BitsIndex`. Since `trailing_zeroes()` always returns a `u32`, all you need to do is constrain that `u32` can index your bits.

```
fn setbit<T>(mask: &mut T)
where
    T: Bits + PrimInt,
    u32: BitsIndex<T>, // <----
{
    let pos = mask.trailing_zeros();
    mask.set_bit(pos, false);
}
```

Comment: This solution is much cleaner. I didn't know the left side of trait bound could be a concrete type like that. Thanks.